# Android (Xamarin.Android) Calendar with both direction swiping

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a task to create a calendar which can change dates on years and month. Months will change by **vertical swipe**, years - **horizontal swipe**.

I think that the best way is using fragments. But everything that I have found is using a ViewPager. But it is not a good decision because I can't make it change years (and months) in one viewpager. ViewPager inside ViewPager is useless for me (please, **do not** advice me project **DoubleViewPager**).

That is why may be it is possible to use just swipe direction detection and only two-three fragments that will be changing endless and animation of every fragment will change depending on direction? 
But I don't know how to do it. All fragments must be in FragmentTransactions, mustn't they? In this case how can I change fragment in transactions dynamically and send arguments to fragment during swipe on a fragment?

Please, tell me is it possible and how could it be?

Comment: I think you misunderstood about the use of fragments and layouts, viewpager is quiet the right control for this scenario, if you don't want to use it, try to use a vertical listview inside a horizontal recyclerview.

Comment: **Grace Feng - MSFT**, thank for you reply. I wouldn't ask to help me if I watched that ViewPager is right solution for my problem.
I solved it by another way without listview and recyclerview and it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution. For my purposes **GestureOverlayView** is very applicable. I can do every moves on screen and change animation and fragment parameters in this case.
Thanks to everybody.